# Unresolved reference: text

Tags: android, kotlin

Please help me figure out this Unresolved Error.
The code below gives an

> Unresolved reference: text
> below code is of
> birthdayGreeting.kt

```
package com.example.birthdaygreet

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class BirthdayGreeting : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object{
        const val NAME_EXTRA = "name_extra"
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_birthday_greeting)
        val name = intent.getStringExtra(NAME_EXTRA)
        BirthdayGreeting.text="happyBirthday$name"
    }
}
```

The error according to android studio is in

> birthdayGreeting.text = "Happy Birthday $name"
> Here is code of main activity

```
    package com.example.birthdaygreet

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun createBirthdayCard(view: View) {
        val name =nameInput.editableText.toString()
        val intent = Intent(this,BirthdayGreeting::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(BirthdayGreeting.NAME_EXTRA,name)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your R.layout.* files?

Comment: You have no static variable "text" so that is incorrect BirthdayGreeting.text. If you want to set text to the TextView you need to sign id for this TextView for example "myTextView" and then set text in activity like this: myTextView.text =  "happyBirthday$name"

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong synthetic import for the `BirthdayGreeting` class. You should use `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_birthday_greeting.*` instead of the `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`